# Wavy walls on one axis (not ringing)

Tags: y-axis, axis

I own an Ender 3 max and after I did a fan upgrade to the main board (In the progress I need to let the printer sit on the y axis motor and might bend something), there're wavy patterns on the wall parrallel to the y axis (the axis the bed travels).

I don't think the pattern is due to ringing since it is only appears on one axis and the magnitude stays the same.

When I put my hand on the print bed (moves with y axis) I can feel it shakes while moving.

I can't tell anything is damaged from visual inspection.

Has anyone encountered this situation before? How can I fix it?

Wavy y axis wall:
[image: Wavy y axis wall]

Good x axis wall:
[image: Good x axis wall]

Comment: Can you measure the period of the wave? To do this, you'd measure the length of some particular number of oscillations (e.g. 10) and divide that length by the number. Is the period independent of speed, or does it change with print speed?

Comment: Also, if you print a skew object where each layer is offset by some amount in X and Y, does the wave phase peg to the corner, or does it stay in the same absolute position?